# it s about recursive functions in c

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<time.h>

long int A(int m, int n);

main() {
    int x;
    clock_t t1, t2, t;
    t1 = clock();
    x = A(2, 5);
    printf("the value of x is %d\n", x);
    t2 = clock();
    t = (t2 - t1) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("decoding time =%d\n", t);
    return 0;
}

int A(int m, int n) {
    if (n == 0) {
        return 1;
    }
    else if(m == 0) {
        return 2*n;
    }
    else  {
        return A(m - 1, A(m, n - 1));
    }
}
```

Why is this code producing runtime errors like `Unhandled exception at 0x002F16C9 in Console Application75.exe: 0xC00000FD: Stack overflow (parameters: 0x00000001, 0x01202FA8)`?

Comment: What values are you calling `A` with? And what's the actual answer you expect?

Comment: I am calling A with 2 and 5

Comment: I want it to be executed and print a result i.e. x

Comment: I can't recall the name of that algorithm, but the whole purpose of it is to demonstrate that it's not computable, even with small arguments. That is, it's specifically designed to overflow the stack.

Comment: This looks rather similar to the [Ackermann function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ackermann_function). Running this code will probably cause your stack to explode even with small arguments.

Comment: ok, but is my programming approach  correct? or something wrong with my code

Comment: @squeamishossifrage Yes, that's the one.

Comment: @user3386109: The function is blatantly computable. In fact, there's code given to compute it right here. ("Computable" has a very specific meaning.)

Comment: @ReddyKowshikk Apart from the ghastly formatting... well, you declared function `A()` as both `int` and `long int`. That won't help. You should also have `int main()`,  not just `main()`. Perhaps using `long long` integers for all the variables would help, but you'll still get the stack overflow problems, I imagine.

Comment: then how to overcome this problem and print a result @squeamishossifrage

Comment: @KerrekSB As I said, I couldn't remember the name. The correct statement is that the function is an example *"of a total computable function that is not primitive recursive."* So yes, you are correct. However, no present day computer can compute it, even for small values.

Comment: @ReddyKowshikk All the outputs of this function appear to be powers of 2. Try to figure out how these powers relate to the values of `m` and `n`, and derive an expression that calculates `A(m,n)` directly without using recursion. For example, I think you'll find that `A(1,i) == 2**i` for all values of `i`.

Comment: i tried to derive the relation but I am getting like A(2,0)=1,A(2,1)=2,A(2,2)=4,A(2,3)=16,A(2,4)=65536 I have no clue how to solve this @squeamishossifrage

Comment: ya now i found something interesting about the series A(2,1)=2^A(2,0) similarly A(2,5)= 2^A(2,4)=2^65536 but the problem is that i am getting infinity @squeamishossifrage

Comment: It's definitely a stack overflow. With a 1Mb stack I get a stack overflow but with a 4Mb stack the program runs fine.

Comment: @user3386109: I'm not sure how to interpret that. You can clearly execute `A(0, 0)` or `A(1, 1)` successfully. And you also won't be able to compute `exp(exp(exp(1000000)))`, on any real machine, either. Where do you draw the line?

Comment: @KerrekSB That seems like a [straw man argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Straw_man), unless you're implying that `exp` is normally implemented with recursion.

Comment: @user3386109: No, I was trying to make the point that computability is not about practical realizability. It's more about formal structure. Real limits apply to any real machine, and the limits may be different for different problems.

Comment: @KerrekSB I believe that I already said, "Yes, you are correct". You have a very precise definition of computability, and I don't dispute your definition.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows you can increase the stack size by linking with e.g. `/stack:4000000` to get a stack size of 4000000 bytes.

In Visual Studio proceed like this:

- Project-Properties
- Under Configuration Properties->Linker->System put e.g 4000000 under *Stack Reserve Size*

[image]

Comment: Though i changed the stack to 4MB same result the program is not working

Comment: @ReddyKowshikk try 8Mb. Was it exactly the same program as the one in the question ?`

Comment: Yeah same program